# How to databind to a property in a WPF Usercontrol?

Tags: c#, data-binding, xaml

I have a `Usercontrol` in a `UserControl` library (separate assembly). I have in my XAML markup like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CenterTextTemplate.CenterTextTemplate"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"  
Name="Test"
Height="Auto" 
Width="Auto">    
<Grid>
    <!--<TextBlock Name="TextField" Text="{Binding Text}"></TextBlock>      -->
    <Viewbox VerticalAlignment="Center" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock  Name="TextField" 
                    Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=Test}" 
                    Foreground="Red" FontSize="50">
        </TextBlock>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

In my .cs file i have a property:

```
public string Text { get { return "test"; } }
```

When I load the usercontrol I see no "test" text... is there something I'm missing? Tried to not give a Name to the usercontrol but that didnt work either...

**EDIT:**

In this setup I get this error:

> Error 1   The type name 'CenterTextTemplate' does not exist in the type
>   'CenterTextTemplate.CenterTextTemplate'   C:\Documents and
>   Settings\Brian Hvarregaard\My Documents\Visual Studio
>   2008\Projects\GreenWeb
>   Templates\CenterTextTemplate\CenterTextTemplate.xaml  4   37  CenterTextTemplate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a dependency property to bind to a property. See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750428.aspx) as well as the msdn page for [`DependencyProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.aspx).

Comment: But i only want to set the properties ONCE when i create an instance of the usercontrol - isnt dependencyproperties a bit overkill for that. All i want the textblock to do is take the text from my "Text" code behind property... thats it

Answer (score 0):

For Binding either you have to make it DependencyProperty or you have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface. If you don't ant to go either way, don't use binding, instead directly assign the values.

You can Bind with CLR property by using BindingMode=OneWayToSource